# Semantic not parsing Elisp files

Tags: elisp, semantic-mode

Here's my Semantic config:

```
(semantic-mode 1)
```

So my config probably isn't the issue.

Whenever I try to use Semantic commands in an elisp file, I get the message `Buffer was not parsed by Semantic.`. So I tried doing `semantic-force-refresh` and it says, `Buffer reparsed.` (no errors). But it still throws the "not parsed" error when I try to use a semantic command.

`$ emacs -Q --eval "(semantic-mode 1)"` has the same issue.

Everything works as intended in `c-mode` and `c++-mode`. What gives?

Version info:

```
CEDET Version:  2.0
            Requested   File        Loaded
  Package       Version     Version     Version
  ----------------------------------------------------------
  cedet:        2.0     nil     ok
  eieio:        1.4     nil     ok
  semantic:     2.2     nil     ok
  srecode:      1.2     nil     Not Loaded
  ede:          1.2     nil     ok
```

I usually use Emacs in Cygwin:

```
GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (i686-pc-cygwin) of 2014-10-21 on desktop-new
```

But I have the same problem on my Arch VPS:

```
GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.14.3) of 2014-10-21 on bitzer.hoetzel.info
```

**EDIT:** I discovered that `(semantic-active-p)` returns `nil` in elisp buffers. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by downloading and installing a recent snapshot of CEDET from here: http://www.randomsample.de/cedet-snapshots/

I used this snapshot: `cedet_snapshot-rev_8698.tar.gz  29-Dec-2014 21:00   1.5M`

I guess the version shipped with this version of Emacs is broken.